# tabs link not stopping the default action

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

I have the following code for jquery tabs each time each time i click on a tab it goes to top of the page:

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li id="fixtures_tab"><a href="#fixtures"><?php echo ALL;?></a></li>
            <li id="live_tab"><a href="#live"><?php echo LIVE;?></a></li>
            <li id="finished_tab"><a href="#finished"><?php echo FINISHED;?></a></li>
            <li id="program_tab"><a href="#program"><?php echo PROGRAM;?></a></li>
            <li id="postpond_tab"><a href="#postpond"><?php echo POSTPOND;?></a></li>
            <li id="selected_tab"><a onclick="stripe_Color();" id='f' href="#fav"><?php echo SELECTED;?> (0)</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-container">
            <div id="fixtures" class="tab-content"><script type="text/javascript">
            </script></div>
            <div id="live" class="tab-content"><script type="text/javascript"></script></div>
            <div id="finished" class="tab-content"><script type="text/javascript"></script></div>
            <div id="program" class="tab-content"><script type="text/javascript"></script></div>
            <div id="postpond" class="tab-content"><script type="text/javascript"></script></div>
            <div id="fav" class="tab-content"><script type="text/javascript"></script></div>
        </div>
```

so i use some jquery line to solve the problem as following :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){

    $('.tabs').find('li').each(function(){
        var stay = $(this).find('a');
        $(this).find('a').click(function(e){
                alert('test');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
    }, 3000);
});
```

the alert is working but the e.preventDefault(); is not . Is there anything wrong about the code???

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.tabs').find('li').each(function(){
      var stay = $(this).find('a');
      $(this).find('a').click(function(e){
        alert('test');
        return false;
      });
    });
  }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: not worked. do you figure out why the alert works while the e.preventDefault() does not?

Comment: I try this code it is not moving up but it is not showing the new tab